# df shown size much smaller than partition size, /home full

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage, partitioning, disk-management

I'm having trouble at the moment because my `/home` partition appears to be full and its usable space seems to be much smaller than the actual disk, which is the confusing part.

this is the line in `fstab` where my home partition gets mounted:

```
#home
UUID=6e6a584b-fa83-439b-bca2-1772b65a3cf2  /home          ext4    defaults      0       0
```

In gnome disks, this is shown as a 256gb partition covering the entire disk (and that's apparently 99% full, which shouldn't be true): [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROIjY.png)

The confusing part is the following output of `df -Th | sort`, where `/home` is shown as only 28gb in size:

```
df -Th | sort
/dev/loop10    squashfs   88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop16    squashfs  5,0M  5,0M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/42
/dev/sda1      ext4       28G   25G  1,1G  97% /home
/dev/sdb2      ext4      117G   28G   83G  26% /
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs     3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     3,9G   41M  3,9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     789M   16K  789M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs          tmpfs     789M  1,9M  787M   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     789M   36K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
udev           devtmpfs  3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
```

I just don't get what's going on here... Can someone help me out? My machine is also slowing down significantly in certain situations now where it hasn't before, which I hope to fix after I understand where all the disk space went.

here's another image of the gnome disk usage analyzer, where home is also 28GB: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb6Gc.png)
edit: BTW, `.cache/dconf` is less than a `kb` in size

output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 238,5G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0 118,8G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Please run `lsblk` command and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Get a backup of all your data  **[ THIS IS IMPORTANT DO NOT SKIP IT ]**
2. Boot your system using a live Ubuntu disk
3. Run:

   ```
   lsblk /dev/sda1 -o size
   ```

   It should return:

   ```
   SIZE
   238,5G
   ```

   Now that we are 100% sure that `/dev/sda1` is the actually your home partition we will continue.
4. Run check disk on your home partition:

   ```
   sudo e2fsck /dev/sda1
   ```
5. Run:

   ```
   sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
   ```
6. Mount the partition:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
7. Check the size of filesystem:

   ```
   df -h --out=size /mnt
   ```

It might help fix the issue.

Comment: `e2fsck` needs `-f` flag, otherwise `resize2fs` says `Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/sda1' first.`

Comment: Might be good to tell what the problem is suspected to be, what these commands do and how they should help in the situation.